# How to close specific Chrome profile that was opened with cmd/bat?

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file, cmd

I need to close all windows of a specific Chrome profile. Suppose I execute:

```
chrome.exe -remote-debugging-port=4000 --user-data-dir=F://chrome
```

in cmd/bat to open a new Chrome profile. I need to close this specific Chrome profile from cmd/bat.

I have tried this:

```
taskkill /IM chrome.exe -remote-debugging-port=4000 --user-data-dir=F://chrome
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using the batch file below:

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims=," %%a in ('wmic process where "caption='chrome.exe'" get processID^,commandline /format:csv ^| FIND "-remote-debugging-port=4000 --user-data-dir=F://chrome"') do set _pid=%%a
taskkill /f /pid %_pid% /t
```

### Explanation

- `wmic process where "caption='chrome.exe'" get processID^,commandline /format:csv` lists all `chrome.exe` processes with the command line used to launch them and the process ID that we will use to kill it.
- Piping (`|`) this into `FIND "-remote-debugging-port=4000 --user-data-dir=F://chrome"` will return only the `chrome.exe` process started with the command you used.
- `for /f "tokens=3 delims=," %%a in ("...") do set _pid=%%a` will set the `_pid` environment variable to the process ID of the process we want to kill.

  The `wmic` command combined with the `find` command should only give us a single result. If you used the command multiple times, then this will only find the process ID of the last process in the list.
- `taskkill /f /pid %_pid% /t`:

  - `/f` forces the task to end, because otherwise Chrome will remain open.
  - `/pid %_pid%` will supply the process ID we got in the `for` loop.
  - `/t` tells `taskkill` to kill the entire process tree.

    Since every Chrome tab and extension runs in its own process, we want to make sure these get killed as well.

Comment: not working ..its not closing that specific browser that was opened

Comment: What do you see if you just run `wmic process where "caption='chrome.exe'" get processID^,commandline /format:csv | FIND "-remote-debugging-port=4000 --user-data-dir=F://chrome"` in the console? Try removing `-remote-debugging-port=4000` from the command and just use the `--user-data-dir` portion.

Comment: cmd execute so fast and close itself not letting me to see anything in the console.tried removing -remote-debugging-port=4000 ..still same..not working

Comment: Try opening the command prompt manually and then running the script or adding `PAUSE` at the end. That will keep the command window open.

Comment: @Mahbubshaun If you run the `for` command directly in the console, you have to change `%%a` to `%a`.

Comment: this does nto seem to work because chrome does not retain all the commandline flags you gave them

Comment: @thatsIch It does strip the command line arguments if you already have Chrome running before you run Chrome with the command line argument you're trying to use. The rest of this still no longer works because Chrome has started adding command line arguments to the subprocesses that contain commas, which screws with the output processing of `wmic`