# Close selenium chrome launched with specific user directory? python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How do I close the chrome windows started using a custom user directory without closing the other chrome windows using different user directories?
Ex:

```
    user_directory = "C:\\Users\\john\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\test"
    config_options = Options()
    config_options.add_argument(f'user-data-dir={user_directory}')
    self.web_driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = config_options)
```

I would want to close only the chrome windows launched using this user directory

This example below is the closest thing I have found to what I need but it is made in batch and I need it in python for windows.

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims=," %%a in ('wmic process where "caption='chrome.exe'" get processID^,commandline /format:csv ^| FIND "-remote-debugging-port=4000 --user-data-dir=F://chrome"') do set _pid=%%a
taskkill /f /pid %_pid% /t
```

Example from: [How to close specific Chrome profile that was opened with cmd/bat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56315428/how-to-close-specific-chrome-profile-that-was-opened-with-cmd-bat)

Comment: you can use `for`-loop in Python and `subprocess` to run `wmic` and `taskkill` - so you could try to convert batch code into Python code.

Comment: you don't need to task kill.  Just use driver.quit().   Each driver is tied to a single session.

Comment: @pcalkins the problem is if I have another chrome window using that same data dir I will get an error saying a window with this dir is already in use if I try to start the program and make a selelium client again. But I have multiple chrome windows open so I only want to close the one that is using the data directory

Comment: Maybe copy that dir and set that as user-data before launching?  Why force-kill a process that's being used?

Comment: For example if I had a python program that created a driver using the call above " self.web_driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = config_options) " it would open a new chrome window using the data dir I set. Now If i took that same chrome instance it opened, opened a tab, separated it from the first instance / tab (so it is its own browser) and then closed the first tab / browser. The python program can be quit and in some cases the second tab I opened using the same dir is still open.

Comment: So now If I started my python program again it will try to launch using that same user dir, but since a chrome window is already open using that dir, it will not open and crash. So instead of crashing I want to make it so it catches that error, finds the chrome process PID using that directory and closes it so I can launch the web driver

Comment: A new tab != a new browser.  (you can't separate it into it's own browser instance)  It's a new windowhandle... you can't use two drivers on one session concurrently.... and doing what you describe would leave the first driver in no-mans land.  Just switch the driver to the new tab's handle.

Comment: There is a hacky way to use more than one driver on one session (getting/setting the sessionID), but that will leave an orphaned browser window open... and it's not useful since Selenium actions have an order... having two drivers controlling one browser would not be useful or predictable.  You can't really control multiple tabs concurrently anyway... there'd always be an order of calls to the wire protocol.   What's your use-case here?  (what are you trying to accomplish by using multiple drivers in one session?)